# Conditional Formatting of duplicate cells in another sheet in Google Sheets

Tags: regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, gs-conditional-formatting, textjoin

What I am trying to do is this:
Sheet1 is a table of unicode CJK characters that I have arranged in a certain way, and Sheet2 is an imported table of unsorted characters. I want to use conditional formatting to highlight the cells in Sheet2 that already exist in Sheet1, with each cell containing one character. In other words, I want ANY cell in Sheet2 that is also in Sheet1 highlighted.

I am using the custom formula with `=countif(Sheet1NamedRange1, A1)>0` on the entire sheet, but it is not doing much. The `match` function would be perfect if it could use a two-dimensional range rather than a 1 dimensional range.

I may be on the wrong path entirely though. Is there any functions that can do this without hard-coding row by row using `match`?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Answer (score 0):

let **J** column be on **Sheet1** then all you need to use is:

```
=REGEXMATCH(B2,TEXTJOIN("|",1,INDIRECT("Sheet1!J:J")))
```

[image]